# запустить exe процесс

Tags: java

Серьёзно, я не могу найти информацию как просто запустить exe файл с помощью Java 1.8

Как вариант(Не рабочий для меня): `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\chromedriver.exe", null, new File("C:\\"));`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10686041/312041

Comment: @tym32167, Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\chromedriver.exe", null, new File("C:\\")); - ничего, ноль реакции, возможно нужно что-то сделать чтобы ошибку во время работы показало?

Comment: ну а процесс создается? Вы в таск менеджере смотрели? Экзешник свой запускали в консоли? Другие перегрузки метода пробовали?

Comment: Нет процесса, перегрузки не использовал. Пробовал различные файлы

Comment: у вас есть пример кода. Вам осталось заставить его работать. Пробуйте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть, он у вас запускается и работает, но вы просто не видите, что он выводит.
Вывод процесса, запущенного таким образом, не выводится на консоль, туда выводится только то, что выводит сама запускалка. Чтобы увидеть, что выводит запущенный процесс, надо забрать у него выходной поток и продублировать его на консоль руками. Этот вывод можно дожидаться и выводить в цикле `while (process.isAlive()) {...}`, но тогда наша программа не закончится, пока не завершит работу запущенный процесс. Альтернативно можно подождать какое-то время с помощью метода `process.waitFor()`, забрать и вывести на консоль всё, что вывел процесс, и выйти, но тогда можно увидеть не весь вывод, часть может потеряться.

Если запускается программа с графическим интерфейсом, а запускала использовала `waitFor()` и не использовала цикла `while (process.isAlive()) {...}`, то через установленное время запускалка кончает работать, а запущенное приложение продолжает работать.

Если запускается консольная программа, которая ждет пользовательского ввода (типа `powershell.exe`), то выглядит так, как будто процесс завис, на самом деле он ждет ввода. Как-то наверное можно ему передавать что-то на вход, но я не разбирался. Разбирайтесь сами: [справка](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String%5B%5D,java.lang.String%5B%5D,java.io.File))

Попробуйте поиграться вот с этим кодом

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Ru_So_1373825_RunExternalExe {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    try {
    // Put here whatever you like
      final String command = "ping 127.0.0.1";
    //  final String command = "notepad.exe";

// С интерактивными консольными приложениями ситуация может 
// выглядеть так, как будто зависло, на самом деле процесс работает, 
// только пока у него на входе ничего нет, он ничего и не выводит
//      final String command = "powershell.exe";
      System.out.println("Running " + command);

      // Run the process
      final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
      System.out.println("Process is alive: " + process.isAlive());

      // Wait for it to finish -- or exit in 30 seconds
      process.waitFor(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      System.out.println("Is it still alive: " + process.isAlive());

      // Has it printed anything out?
      System.out.println("The process printed to its System.out: >>>>");
      final BufferedReader reader =
              new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
      String s;
   // while (process.isAlive()) {
        while (reader.ready() && (s = reader.readLine()) != null)  {
          System.out.println(s);
        }
   // }
      reader.close();

      System.out.println("Фсё!!!");

    } catch (final IOException x) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      x.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

Чтобы получить от запущенного процесса его сообщения об ошибках, нужно забрать у него то, что он выводит на `System.err`. Это делается методом `getErrorStream()`:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(
               new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
```